# Sublime build code

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sublimetext3

Could someone please explain step-by-step how the following build script works?

```
{
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -i -u $file;bash\"'"],
"shell": true
}
```

I know what `-i` does (keeps interpreter open), and the final `bash` keep sthe terminal open, but the rest is inscrutable to me. In particular what do `-e`, `-c` and `-u` do, are they called "flags" and where do I learn more about them? Which parts are specific to Sublime and which are to do with the OS?

Comment: [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) will explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
"gnome-terminal # use this terminal to run the next commands
  -e # execute the following command
   '
     bash -c # read commands from the following string 
       \"
          python3 
            -i # looks like interactive mode (sorry not a python dev)
            -u # force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered
            $file; # tipically this would be a python script, so you 
                   # would end up being able to inspect the environment,
                   # calling functions, seeing their otputs, etc 
          bash # open a new shell
       \"
   '
"
```

I think the only part that could be part of Sublime is `$file` but that depends, with a bit more context on that code I might be able to give a better answer.

- [`gnome-terminal -e`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html)
- [`bash -c`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bash-options.html)
- [`python -i`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2665150/57095)